# download file withough storing file on server? How to give download functionality of file to client withought storing file on server?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, download, outputstream

I am using jasper reports in my liferay portlet and I want that user download the reports directly from the output stream. I don't want to store the reports pdf file on my server.

How can I do this with the jasper report?

```
File pdf = File.createTempFile("output.", ".pdf");
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, new FileOutputStream(pdf));
```

Right now I'm doing this which generate pdf file in some directory and then I provide download link to user. But I want that user just download the pdf from direct ouptut stream.

Answer (score 1):

In your portlet action:

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest request,ResourceResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("application/application-download");
    response.setProperty("Content-disposition", "attachement; filename=<some file.pdf>");

    OutputStream responseStream = response.getPortletOutputStream();

    jasperPrint=...
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, responseStream);

    responseStream.flush();
    responseStream.close();

}
```

Then create the resource download url like this:

```
<a href="<portlet:resourceURL/>">Download Report</a>
```

Comment: ..just this i want to write in ma jsp page after i write this in my serveresource method? <a href="<portlet:resourceURL/>">Download Report</a>

Comment: this throws an error like java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot obtain OutputStream because Writer is already in use

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly you coud try

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream bous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, bous);
  byte[] bytes = bous.toByteArray();
```